# Is there any other $H(s,t)$ which satisfied $H(s,0)=f(2s)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

$\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is  a group with respect to the product $[f][g]=[f.g]$

satisfy three properties

$1. $Associative

$2.$ Identity :$[c]$ where $c$ is the constant loop i,e $c(s)=x_0$ for any $s$

$3.$Inverse

**My question** : How to show the identity  properties in $\pi_1(X,x_0)?$

**My attempt**

$$ f.c(s) \neq c f(s)$$

But    $$[f][c]= [c][f]=[f] \implies fc≃cf≃f$$

First we show that  $fc≃f$

By using product path formula

$f\cdot c(s)= \begin{cases} 
      a& 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
      f(2s-1) & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

and $c\cdot f(s)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2s)& 0\le s\le 1/2 \\
     b & 1/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

From Allen hatcher book diagram

[image]

From  the diagram  we see that  $f .c$ is that path that doesnot move at all   for the first half of the time  but $f.c $ move quickly through $f$ at  double speed for the second half

Now we can conclude that  the homotopy bewteen path $f.c$ and $f$ is given by path that doesn't move for $0\le s \le t/2$ and the uniformly cover that path $f  $ for $t/2  \le s \le 1$

Therefore

$H : I \times I  \to X$ is given by

$H(s,t)= \begin{cases} 
      a& 0\le s\le t/2 \\
      f\left(\frac{2s-t}{2-t}\right) & t/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

$H(s,0)=f(s)$  and $H(s,1)= f.c =f(2s-1) $

This implies that  $H$ is homotopy relative $\{0,1\}$

i,e   $$fc≃f \tag 1$$

Similarly for $cf≃f$ same story , diagram is given in right

[image]

From the diagram we conclude that

$H : I \times I  \to X$ is given by

$H(s,t)= \begin{cases} 
      f\left(\frac{2s}{t+1}\right)& 0\le s\le t/2 \\
      b& t/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

$H(s,0)=f(2s)= c.f$  and $H(s,1)= f(s)  $

This implies that  $H$ is homotopy relative $\{0,1\}$

i,e   $$fc≃f \tag 2$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,we  have

$$fc≃cf≃f$$

hence proved

**My confusion** : In $2$nd part $cf$

I have make this function by coercion  i,e i have take $H(s,t)= \frac{2s}{t+1}$ if $0\le s\le t/2$ where

$H : I \times I  \to X$ is given by

$H(s,t)= \begin{cases} 
      f\left(\frac{2s}{t+1}\right)& 0\le s\le t/2 \\
      b& t/2\le s\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

Is there any other $H(s,t)$ which satisfied $H(s,0)=f(2s)$ according to the given diagram?